# How to correctly anonymize IP for Tag Manager code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager we get this code for placing on pages

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ADSAFASDF');</script>
```

Here we can find the code we should use for anonymizing IP https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ip-anonymization

```
 gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

Where should I place it? If I place it right after the code (before ending `/script` tag or inside separate `script`) using Tag Assistant Chrome extension I can see the error

```
Invalid call to gtag(), the Global site snippet is not installed
```

How to properly insert the code and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Tag Manager doesn't process or store IPs. It is the Google Analytics  tag **inside** of Google Tag Manager that you need to configure to anonymize IPs.

Go to GTM & edit your Google Analytics Tag(s) or Google Analytics Settings Variable:

1. Go to `More Settings > Fields to Set`
2. Add a new field. Configure the field with:

   1. Field name: `anonymizeIp`
   2. Field value: `true`

Comment: actually tag manger does process ips unless you switch it off in both tag manager AND analytics.
be good if there was an answer to the original question on how to do it in code.